# Multiple inputs in one line in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

I've newly started learning C++ and am stuck with this problem. I need to insert a (user inputted) number of elements in a single line with space separation. If the number of elements was known, I could just write `cin >> var1 >> var2 >> ... >> varN;`. But how do I do it with any number of elements (loop maybe)?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        //stuck here
    }
}
```

I could have written `cin >> arr[i];` and proceeded, but that would require the user to press enter after every input, which I cannot do due to the question's restrictions. How do I write the code so that all my input for array elements can be given in a single line?

PS: I've seen several similar questions already answered on the site, but most of them involve implementations using vectors or are beyond my current level of understanding. A simpler solution will be appreciated.

Comment: So, you want each `arr[i]` to be read RIGHT AFTER the user type the space after? That is a bit strange.
Does it make a difference in the final goal you want to achieve? Can you elaborate what are you doing on top of this (if possible)?

Comment: Elements are space separated, so they will all be read after pressing Enter

Comment: there is no language called C/C++. If you want to learn C++ you should read this [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and maybe this 
[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). And note that C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: *'but that would require the user to press enter after every input'* That's completely incorrect, where did you get that idea?

Comment: VLAs are not part of the C++ standard and therefore should not be used. You're incorrect about the behaviour you described though, see https://godbolt.org/z/WqbfrnrMd

Comment: indeed, forgot this one [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin>>arr[i]` does not require the user to press enter after every input.
You just need to give whitespace between the integer inputs. It will scan the array normally.

Comment: This is correct! Just put `cin >> arr[i];` in and test

Comment: Ah, yes it works perfectly! I thought `cin` has newline as default separator for each input and thought there exists some alternative to change it to a whitespace.

Comment: `cin` is a stream, there's no concept of a separator. It's the input operators and functions which might (or might not) define separators.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to replace your array with a `std::vector` to make it resizable in run time. If you do like in your example the program will not compile because `n` is not known when the program is built.

Here is a [simple example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+n+%3D+0%3B%0A++++cin+%3E%3E+n%3B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::string%3E+arr%3B+//+A+vector+(ie+kind+of+a+variable+sized+array)%0A++++for+(int+i%3D0%3B+i%3Cn%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++std::string+str%3B%0A++++++++cin+%3E%3E+str%3B+//+Read+a+word%0A++++++++arr.push_back(str)%3B+//+Add+a+string+to+the+vector%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+arr.size()%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+arr.at(i)+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B+//+Print+value+of+vector%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.31070496083551,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.689295039164485,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    vector<string> arr; // A vector (ie kind of a variable sized array)
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        string str;
        cin >> str; // Read a word
        arr.push_back(str); // Add a string to the vector
    }

    // To use the data
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        cout << arr.at(i) << "\n"; // Print value of vector
    }
    // or like this
    for (auto str: arr) {
        cout << str << "\n";
    }
}
```